How to prove the following equivalent conditions for the convergence of a real sequence $(\alpha_k)_{k\in \mathbb N}$
Background:Given a real sequence denoted by $\alpha=(\alpha_n)_{n{\in}\mathbb{Z}_+}$.
Fix two real numbers $a<b$ and define inductively:$$\begin{aligned}&S_1(\alpha):=\inf\{n\geq0:\alpha_n\leq a\}\\&T_1(\alpha):=\inf\{n\geq S_1(\alpha):\alpha_n\geq b\}\end{aligned}$$ $\forall k\ge 1$
$$\begin{align}
S_{k+1}(\alpha):=\inf\{n\geq T_k(\alpha):\alpha_n\leq a\}\\T_{k+1}(\alpha):=\inf\{n\geq S_{k+1}(\alpha):\alpha_n\geq b\}
\end{align}$$Finally,define$$\begin{align}
N_n([a,b],\alpha):=\sup\{k\geq1:T_k(\alpha)\leq n\}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf{1}_{\{T_k(\alpha)\leq n\}},\\N_\infty([a,b],\alpha):=\sup\{k\geq1:T_k(\alpha)<\infty\}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf{1}_{\{T_k(\alpha)<\infty\}}
\end{align}$$The convention $\inf\varnothing:=+\infty,\sup \varnothing:= 0$ is used in these definitions.

Question:Prove that:$$(\alpha_n)_{n{\in}\mathbb{Z}_+} \text{converges
 in}\ \mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}\Leftrightarrow  \forall a,b\in \mathbb
 Q\ \text{and}\ a<b,N_\infty([a,b],\alpha)<\infty  $$

I was able to prove the $\Rightarrow$ direction but stuck in the $\Leftarrow$ direction.
Here is my attempt at $\Leftarrow$ direction:
$\forall a,b\in \mathbb Q$,$a<b$,Denote $n_{ab}=N_\infty([a,b],\alpha)<\infty$ then $T_{n_{ab}}<\infty$.
If $S_{n_{ab}}(\alpha)=\infty$, then $\forall n\ge n_{ab}+1,\alpha_n>a$ and $T_{n_{ab}+1}=\infty$ by definition of $S_{k}(\alpha)$ and $T_k(\alpha)$
If $S_{n_{ab}}(\alpha)<\infty$,since $T_{n_{ab}+1}=\infty$,we get $\forall n\ge n_{ab}+1,\alpha_n<b$ again by definition of $S_{k}(\alpha)$ and $T_k(\alpha)$.
We now conclude that $\forall a,b\in \mathbb Q,a<b$,there exists $N$ sufficiently large,such that either ($\forall n>N$,$\alpha_n<b$)  or ($\forall n>N$,$\alpha_n>a$) .
But I'm stuck here,since I don't how to get convergence from it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Note:This problem comes from Measure Theory, Probability, and
Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p266.The author state it as a lemma and leave it as an exercise.


For clarity, I think you mean to say that either $\alpha_n<b$ for all $n$ large enough, or $\alpha_n>a$ for all $n$ large enough.
In this case you are almost there - if $(\alpha_n)$ didn't converge then we could let $a<b$ be rationals with $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \alpha_n < a<b<\limsup_{n\to \infty} \alpha_n$$
(since the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ must be distinct). Then from what you've written we have either $\alpha_n<b$ for all $n$ large enough, or $\alpha_n>a$ for all $n$ large enough. But either is impossible by the definition of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$. Hence $(\alpha_n)$ must converge.

You are right.It should be"either ($\forall n>N$,$\alpha_n<b$)  or ($\forall n>N$,$\alpha_n>a$)".
